# MySQL - Change table value when current time reaches midnight

Tags: mysql

We want to change a value in our table when the current time reaches midnight (23:59:59) in our case, but we are unsure on how to approach this. The table has a "startTime" and "endTime" and we want to set the "endTime" to "23:59:59" when the current time reaches midnight, if there is a value in "startTime" in the same row. Can we use stored procedures or triggers to fulfill this requirement? Or is this the wrong way to approach this?

New rows are constantly being added to the table, so it should listen for the change in time continually, or in intervals of once every day.

Comment: Has google stopped working? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to run a scheduler that does this.

You can't link a trigger, because the trigger will only respond to an action performed. Unless you have a user sitting at midnight to perform the action, that won't help you.
Stored procedures are essentially the same thing. It must be user initiated.

Unless you have a scheduler running, that will perform the action for you.
I do believe that is the most common way to do it.

Windows has a built in one. nginx or something like that, I belive its called cron jobs?

Anyway, just google scheduler/cronjobs guide/tutorials, they are way better at explaining it than I am here.

Comment: I think this event scheduler https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/ may help. Otherwise, a linux cronjob may also help.